# Express app throws 500 TypeError: Object #<EventEmitter> has no method 'hrtime'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The staging instance of my webapp is throwing an error:

```
Express
500 TypeError: Object #<EventEmitter> has no method 'hrtime'
   at Object.logger [as handle] (F:\approot\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\node_modules\morgan\index.js:96:28)
   at next (F:\approot\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:169:15)
   at Object.favicon [as handle] (F:\approot\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\node_modules\serve-favicon\index.js:54:44)
   at next (F:\approot\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:169:15)
   at Object.expressInit [as handle] (F:\approot\node_modules\express\lib\middleware.js:30:5)
   at next (F:\approot\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:169:15)
   at Object.query [as handle] (F:\approot\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\query.js:43:5)
   at next (F:\approot\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:169:15)
   at Function.handle (F:\approot\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:177:3)
   at Server.app (F:\approot\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\connect.js:66:37)
```

Line 96 in morgan/index.js:

```
req._startAt = process.hrtime();
```

This only happens on the copy we've deployed to Azure. We are able to run the Express server through node directly on the machine, and everything seems to work perfectly.

We just started having this problem with the most recent deployment. Any idea where to start looking? I can't find any similar issues searching Github issues for Express or Morgan. Google also isn't helping.

Comment: What version of node is your Azure instance using?

Comment: @mscdex This may be my issue. I found that I was using 0.6.4, so I've switched to the latest version offered on Azure Cloud Service. I will report back once it has deployed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`process.hrtime()` only exists in node v0.8.x and newer. So you will need to upgrade to a newer version of node (the latest stable version being preferable) somehow.

Answer (score -1):

It happens because of the version. Try to update to the current version. Here are a few alternatives on how to make the change.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/04/20/nodejs-and-npm-versions-on-azure-app-services/

Comment: You should consider listing out a few of these examples in your answer, so a reader would not need to go to a different site.